# WPF XAML Animation property path not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, properties, path

I'm trying to animate the content of a metro styled button.
My problem is that the content of the button does not change color.
The foreground color does not change.

Here's my button's style:

```
    <Style x:Key="MetroButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
            Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
            Value="88"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="AppButton"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverEllipse"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="PressedEllipse"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    To="Black"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseInnerContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                                    To="#7F8D8D8D"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseInnerContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid Margin="0,14,0,5"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              MinWidth="40">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="PressedEllipse"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Opacity="0"
                                     Width="40"
                                     Height="40"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="MouseOverEllipse"
                                     Fill="#7F8D8D8D"
                                     Opacity="0"
                                     Width="40"
                                     Height="40"/>
                            <Ellipse Fill="Transparent"
                                     Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     StrokeThickness="2"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="EllipseInnerContent"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="LabelText"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                   FontSize="12"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's is how i use it.
This does not works:

```
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonStyle}"
                                Tag="Blah">
                            <TextBlock Text="XXX"/>
                        </Button>
```

This works:

```
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MetroButtonStyle}"
                                Tag="Blah"
                                Content="XXX"/>
```

Comment: TextBlock is not a Control. TextBlock is a FrameworkElement. That is the reason why animating the Control.Foreground property doesn't work.

Comment: Changing TargetProperty to Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" does not change anything. Can it even work at all?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856780/in-a-buttons-control-template-how-can-i-set-the-color-of-contained-text) is a similar question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseInnerContent"
```

in your animations, where `EllipseInnerContent` is a `ContentPresenter` and there's no `Foreground` property on `ContentPresenter`.

Change it to `ContentControl`.

Also, when putting a `TextBlock` as a content of a control, it will inherit the foreground of the page\user control that it's part of. Use `DataTemplate` instead to have the `TextBlock` created for you and then it will inherit the foreground from the button.